# Foundation for Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just went through a 4 week Discrete Mathematics course and I passed by the skin of my teeth. I was wondering how I can cover my foundations by learning what would normally come before such a course. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be mighty thankful. Discrete Mathematics materials starting from square one would also be helpful. Recommendations for books, lectures, games, etc would all be great.
Cheers

Comment: "A First Course in Discrete Mathematic" by Molluzzo and Buckley is a gently paced set of material, not withstanding the answer given.

Answer (score 0):

"Discrete mathematics" is not really a well-defined thing of its own. It is an umbrella term that usually means, more or less, "the amount of mathematics computer science students need to know".

In particular, it doesn't have a well-defined starting point. Different schools start their discrete mathematics courses at the level of prior knowledge they generally assume *all* incoming students in STEM fields to have -- but what this is varies from country to country and sometimes from institution to institution.

A course that aims to get up to "the usual" discrete-mathematics topics in just four weeks sounds rather fast -- so either you were in a course that assumed more background knowledge than is common, or a course that skipped many of the usual topics, or a course that was simply extremely accelerated. It is not really possible to tell based on your question.

My best advice would be to ask more specific questions about the *particular* areas of the course you were struggling with.

Comment: I see, I see. Well here's what the course looked like:
Week 1 Logic I and II. 
Week 2 Set Theory and Functions. Week 3 Sequences, Summations and Matrices with Number Theory. Week 4 Combinatorics and Efficiency of Algorithms. I would like to cover all that again because as you said, one month wasn't enough to get a full grasp on all of this. The text book we had wasn't very great either.

Comment: Molluzzo and Buckley would not be suitable for that material. Just shows what a catch all "discrete maths" is.

Comment: I'll still take a look at it. Got any good materials on the above subjects by chance?